# Notice: Undefined index: ID - Deleting record based on ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've read the other threads and still unable to figure this out.
I'm trying to delete a record within the DB based on it's ID.
This code is where the item to be delete is coming from.

```
echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['site_name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['site_code'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['site_address'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['site_city'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['site_postalcode'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id_province'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id_country'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="/delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">delete</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="/modify.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">modify</a></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

My delete.php contains the following:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project1");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sites_id=$_GET['ID']; 
    if (isset($sites_id)) { 
       $query = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM sites WHERE ID='$sites_id'");  
    }
?>
```

I get the Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\wamp\www\delete.php on line 8

Comment: Well, do you have an ID parameter?

Comment: Could be the single quotes around your $Sites_id.  ID is generally a number, is this the case?

Comment: $_GET['ID'] should be $_GET['id'];

Comment: I think this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: you know what undefined means? means there's no `ID` key in the array on line 8. Probably because there's no `ID` in your array on line 8. what about making sure you try and get the right index?! :)

Comment: @marc b was right... it was the upper and lower case causing the issue. Now i have another... getting Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is case sensitive for array keys:

```
    echo '<td><a href="/modify.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">modify</a></td>';
                                   ^^---lower case
$sites_id=$_GET['ID']; 
                 ^^---upper case
```

As far as PHP is concerned, `ID` and `id` are two completely different array keys.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$_GET['ID']` when you should have `$_GET['id']`. These keys are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In html your id is in lowercase and in php in uppercase...

also change the line

```
$sites_id = $_GET['ID']; 

if (isset($sites_id))
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))

$sites_id = $_GET['id'];
```